# How to only Load scripts on variable products page

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I'm looking for a way to load my JavaScript and CSS only on the product page, but only if it's a Variable Products.

The `is_product()` function works well, but my scripts are loaded for all types of products: Simple, Variable, Grouped .....

How to limit the loading of scripts only for a variable product?

Comment: Maybe something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25159437)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already tried this solutions :

```
$the_product = new WC_Product(get_the_ID());
$the_product->get_type();  // Return always "simple"
```

So, I followed the documentation of the code  `Class WC_Product()`:

```
/**
 * Get the product if ID is passed, otherwise the product is new and empty.
 * This class should NOT be instantiated, but the wc_get_product() function
 * should be used. It is possible, but the wc_get_product() is preferred.
 *
 * @param int|WC_Product|object $product Product to init.
 */
```

Now I get the correct product type with this:

```
    $the_product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );
    var_dump( $the_product->get_type() );
```

The output is correct :

```
string(8) "variable"
```

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce conditional to test if a Product is Variable.

```
global $product
if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ){

  // a variable product

}
```

Found it here: https://gist.github.com/patrickgilmour/9d4a28b4a2f0c1dcecbf and here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/condition-to-check-if-product-is-simple-or-variable.

Comment: Hi , this solution return always `simple` . we must use `wc_get_product` instead of `WC_Product` class